# C:Function not returning correct value

Tags: c, arrays, function, return-value, return-type

The purpose of this program is to print as much input text as possible (up to the array limit) but it should explicitly return the exact length (numerical  value) of the input text.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int line_input(char array[], int maxlinelimit);
void copy(char toarray[], char fromarray[]);

int line_input(char s[], int limit)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    for(; ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i)
    {
        s[i] = ch;
    }
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = ch;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}

int main()
{
    int length;
    length = 0;
    int max;
    max = 0;
    char line[MAXLINE], longest[MAXLINE];
    while((length = line_input(line, MAXLINE) > 0))
    {
        printf("%d\n%s\n", length, line);
        if(length > max)
        {
            max = length;
            copy(longest, line);
        }

    }
    if(max > 0)
    {
        printf("\n\n%d is the size of the longest line\n", max);
        printf("%s\n\n", longest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will find that the user-defined function named "line_input()" isn't returning the value it should due to some reason I do not know. I don't think there is any warning which I haven't tackled hopefully.

*Please see if you can fix it.*

**P.S.** - *input text is any character string from the keyboard. Pressing "Enter" will start a new line though.*

Comment: It is weird that the argument `limit` isn't used. By the way, I suggest you should begin with changing `(length = line_input(line, MAXLINE) > 0)` to `(length = line_input(line, MAXLINE)) > 0` and have the system save the return value itself to `length`.

Comment: "...isn't returning the value it should due ..." is not as helpful as stating 1) what value it does return 2) what value was expected 3) the input.

Answer (score 1):

- You have to use `int`, which can safely store all (not multi-byte) charcters and `EOF`, to store the result of `getchar()`.
- You must limit the length to save to avoid buffer overrun.
- Stopped counting the newline character to make the return value more acccurate.

Try this:

```
int line_input(char s[], int limit)
{
    int ch;
    int i = 0, index = 0;
    for(; ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i)
    {
        if (index < limit - 1) s[index++] = ch;
    }
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        if (index < limit - 1) s[index++] = ch;
    }
    s[index] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}
```

Also note that the type of `limit`, `i`, `index` and the return value should be `size_t` because they are dealing with size.

**UPDATE:** another version which can tell blank line from end of input and with some more improvements

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int line_input(char s[], int limit);
void copy(char to[], const char from[]);

int line_input(char s[], int limit)
{
    int ch;
    int i = 0, index = 0;
    for(; ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i)
    {
        if (index < limit - 1) s[index++] = ch;
    }
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        if (index < limit - 1) s[index++] = ch;
    }
    else if(ch == EOF && index == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    s[index] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], const char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}

int main(void)
{
    int length = 0;
    int max = 0;
    char line[MAXLINE], longest[MAXLINE];
    while((length = line_input(line, MAXLINE)) >= 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n%s\n", length, line);
        if(length > max)
        {
            max = length;
            copy(longest, line);
        }

    }
    if(max > 0)
    {
        printf("\n\n%d is the size of the longest line\n", max);
        printf("%s\n\n", longest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This approach does not signify when `EOF` occurred.  Suggest returning `EOF` when _only_ `EOF` was returned from `fgetc()`.

Comment: By not counting `'\n'`, when a line consisting of only `"\n"` occurs, this function will stop OP's `while((length = line_input(line, MAXLINE) > 0))` even if additional lines exists

Comment: Just a nit, always safer to test `index + 1 < limit` rather than `index < limit - 1`. (*note* this is a small nit that protects against various conversions and sign-extension, e.g. if `limit` is *unsigned* and inadvertently zero) @chux must have hit the eggnog a bit over the holidays.... he usually raises that as well. `:)`

Comment: @David C. Rankin And using `size_t` instead of `int limit` is usually better to index and size limit arrays.  MCHNY.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In that case `index + 1` would fail if `index` was the maximum of its type, so there is no hard and fast rule

Comment: Agreed. There are caveats to just about all setups there. Between the last 3 comments I think they are pretty well fleshed out. Knowing the relevant considerations will allow a proper choice for any given situation.

Comment: @chux can you tell me how am I supposed to use size_t instead of the current implementation in my code?

Comment: I was trying to do it with minimum constructs and keywords. As simple as possible. I know yours is pretty same but still I'm trying to stick to my code due to the fact that it would be easy to introduce to others. I'm really looking forward to get a feel for it. It'll take time though. And my code was really just a job doer kind of code. I haven't really analyzed it from the point of possibilities and testing. Using int over char is a point I remembered but I think it was some issue which occurred at that time due to which I replaced the int. You're right regarding using int though.

Comment: @Avineshwar [request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476577/cfunction-not-returning-correct-value/34476749?noredirect=1#comment56715864_34476749) is really another post.  Not proper to post under this good answer (too long), nor as another answer as it does not address this question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your line_input() function:

```
int line_input(char s[], int limit)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    for(; ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i)
    {
        s[i] = ch;
    }
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = ch;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return i;
}
```

You are only incrementing your variable 'i' when 'ch' is a newline character. Put your increment in the for loop as follows:

```
for(; ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'); ++i){
    s[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
```

You can decide if you want to keep the increment for newline characters or not by keeping or removing the increment from the `if(ch == '\n')` body if you choose to.

Comment: I saw and corrected that. Thanks for pointing it out though. I missed it due to multitasking.